# How many GB of data can be written to an 80GB Intel 320 series SSD?

Tags: ssd, hardware-failure

I bought a used 80GB SSD on eBay and checked it with CrystalDiskInfo.  Its saying 36,000GB have been written on the SSD.
**How much data can be written before failure?**

Comment: My question is clearly about **data written** on my hard drive.  It is not an open-ended theoretical question like the 285 year question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How much data can be written before failure?

I am going to extrapulate the data to answer this question.  An Intel SSD 320 (300GB) and Intel SSD 320 Review (80GB) both use the same Intel 25nm NAND.  The Intel 320 has an estimate lifespam of upto 60 TBW (Total Bytes Written).

I would estimate that the Intel 320 80GB would then have an estimated 16 TBW lifespan, which is approximately 26% of lifespan of the 300GB, due to it being 26.6% of the storage space.

[image]

[Intel SSD 320 Review (300GB)](http://www.storagereview.com/intel_ssd_320_review_300gb)

Comment: Doesn't TBW stand for Terabytes Written? 60 bytes seems really low :)